# MySQL select dependant on time of day

Tags: mysql

I want to select from a MySQL table and filter depending on the time of day:

```
if now > 10am select uploaded date where created date is today

if now < 10am select uploaded date where created date is yesterday
```

Comment: Subtract 10 hours. I.e. Just get the stuff from whatever date it was 10 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must use [Cron jobs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for this.

Then, your sql will look like that:

```
WHERE tbl.TimeCreated = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

assuming this format of the field: `DateTime(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS)`

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need.

```
SELECT
    `uploaded_date`
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    `created_date` = CASE WHEN CURTIME() > 100000
                       THEN CURDATE()
                       ELSE CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
                     END
```

You can see a similar example in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/29993) which should return a single row of "AM" in the morning, "Noon" at noon, and "PM" in the afternoon (and 2 empty result sets).